# UIImage** for change dynamically value of UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimageview, uiimage

i have try to create an Image Controller for store image and reuse it when need during one instance of application, this is my class
[Nota: the method controllaDictionary search the key of the image if is was just used (explain on detail above)]

```
-(void)imageContentUrl:(NSString*)imageURL andImage:(UIImage**)image{

NSLog(@"Stampa Immagine Contente URL: %@",imageURL);

NSString* imageName = [[imageURL componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] lastObject];

if([self controllaDictionary:imageName]){
    NSLog(@"||| IMMAGES ---------> Image Exixt in Dictionary");
    UIImage* imageInDict = [self controllaDictionary:imageName];
    image = &imageInDict;
    return;
}else{

    UIImage* imageFile = nil;

    if([imageName isEqualToString:@""] || imageName == nil){
        NSLog(@"||| IMMAGES ------- Null Link");
        image = nil;
    }

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",_imageDirectory,imageName]]){
        NSLog(@"||| IMMAGES ------- Exist in Folder: %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",_imageDirectory,imageName]);
        imageFile = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",_imageDirectory,imageName]];
        image = &imageFile;
        [self.imageDict setValue:imageFile forKey:imageName];
        return;
    }else{
        NSLog(@"||| IMMAGINI ------- Miss, Start Download at URL: %@",imageURL);

        [self downloadImageAtUrl:imageURL andImagePointer:image withHendlerBlock:^(NSError *error, UIImage *image, NSString *urlImage,UIImage** doubleImagePointer) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"Stampa Double Pointer IMG -> %@",image);
                doubleImagePointer = &image;
                [self saveImage:image andName:imageName];
                [self.imageDict setValue:image forKey:imageName];
            }else{
                NSLog(@"Stampa Errore: %@",error);
            }
        }];
    }
  }
}

-(void)downloadImageAtUrl:(NSString*)urlImage andImagePointer:(UIImage**)image withHendlerBlock:(void(^)(NSError* error,UIImage* imageDownloaded,NSString* urlImage,UIImage** doubleImagePointer))dowloadImageBlock{

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    UIImage* downloadImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlImage]]];
    NSError* error = nil;

    if (downloadImg) {
        NSLog(@"Immagine Acquisita");

    }else{
        NSLog(@"Errore Download Compilazione Errore");
        error = [NSError errorWithDomain:DownloadErrorDomain code:0 userInfo:@{DownloadErrorDomain: @"Errore nel download dell'immagine, non si hanno a disposizione ulteriori strumenti per comprenderne la natura. Effettuare un ceck della URL"}];
    }

    dowloadImageBlock(error,downloadImg,urlImage,image);
});

}



@end
```

ok after this i explain you how wath i have to do:

QUickly is a singleton instance that search in a specific Folder if there is a Image.

Yes set image and done, No start dowload then set and done.

I have see that this method is powerfull for memory management because i create a NSMutabeDictionary with the name of image like a key and the UIImage for value so i use only one pointer for multiple instance of same image [then i allocate in memory the image only first time].

```
-(void)imageContentUrl:imageURL andImage:(UIImage**)image
```

this method search in the dir if file exist and set the image-> now i would operate like sometime run NSError so i pass to this method an UIImage**
like this

```
UIImage* image = nil;

[[GestoreImmagini instance] imageContentUrl:@"URL/Immage/For/Download.jpg" andImage:&image];

[self.imageEvent setImage:image];
```

the in async i set the image.

this is my Idea but the image are downloaded and set (and if i log, are printed on console) but self.imageEvent don't show the image... Some one can help me?

**@Edit After Cy-4AH Answer**

Correct!! Is my fault... after C++ i have pass more time to work without pointer and i have forgot somting...

tnx but now the second portion of the code after dowload and the return from the block the image was not set... [with correction of *]

```
[self downloadImageAtUrl:imageURL andImagePointer:image withHendlerBlock:^(NSError *error, UIImage *image, NSString *urlImage,UIImage** doubleImagePointer) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Stampa Double Pointer IMG -> %@",image);
            *doubleImagePointer = image;
            [self saveImage:image andName:imageName];
            [self.imageDict setValue:image forKey:imageName];
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Stampa Errore: %@",error);
        }
    }];
```

why? on theory the pointer is the same...

**@Edit After DEBUG**

i have found problem here at the log 2.0 , 2.1 and 2.2 the image print (null) and this i correct because i not have set it but in 2.3 i have a crash for BAD_ACCESS like miss all References. and same happens when i print it in the dowloadImageBlock().

```
-(void)downloadImageAtUrl:(NSString*)urlImage andImagePointer:(UIImage**)image withHendlerBlock:(void(^)(NSError* error,UIImage* imageDownloaded,NSString* urlImage,UIImage** doubleImagePointer))dowloadImageBlock{

 NSLog(@" 2.0 - ||| ----- --------  -----------> %@",*image);

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

NSLog(@" 2.1 - ||| ----- --------  -----------> %@",*image);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    NSLog(@" 2.2 - ||| ----- --------  -----------> %@",*image);
    UIImage* downloadImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlImage]]];
    NSError* error = nil;

    if (downloadImg) {
        NSLog(@"Immagine Acquisita");

    }else{
        NSLog(@"Errore Download Compilazione Errore");
        error = [NSError errorWithDomain:DownloadErrorDomain code:0 userInfo:@{DownloadErrorDomain: @"Errore nel download dell'immagine, non si hanno a disposizione ulteriori strumenti per comprenderne la natura. Effettuare un ceck della URL"}];
    }

     NSLog(@" 2.3 - ||| ----- --------  -----------> %@",*image);

    dowloadImageBlock(error,downloadImg,urlImage,image);
});

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missanderstanding in working with pointers.
It's should be:

```
*image = imageInDict;
```

Also you download image asynchroniously, and yours variable located in function call stack is already destroyed, when you try assign value to it. You should better use `UIImageView*` or some other objective-c class that have `UIImage*` in properties instead `UIImage**`

Comment: Any idea to controll dowload of image?

Comment: Tnx for help... I have found nother way :) Regards